# Htmlunit Runtimeexception

Tags: java, htmlunit

Trying to grab a page with HtlmUnit, the goal is to programmatically log in to Tumblr, but getting back this error right off the bat when I get the page:

```
    Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. (https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/vendor/yahoo/rapid/rapid-3.31.js?_v=292c65401666920d8f451dda27a5b52c#2)
```

Seems like a javascript error, however i set setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) so no idea.
My code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); 
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        try {
    HtmlPage page1 = page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.tumblr.com/login");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for your help, appreciate it!